# how to make parent component pass prop to children only when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass props from AddPost component to AllPosts component only when button is clicked in AddPost.

Plus how to keep on adding new posts' data(post,title,keyid) from AddPost in a object "newArray" in AllPosts every time button is clicked and this new data gets saved in allposts array and then every post is displayed by applying map function on it.

I am facing problem about how can I get new data from AddPost in newObject and continuously keep pushing this in allposts array?

AddPost.js

```
class Addpost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  
          title : '',
          post : '',
          keyid : 0
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value
      })
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({   
         keyid : prevState.keyid + 1,
         post : '',
         title : ''
    }));
         console.log(this.state.keyid);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} maxLength="30" placeholder="Title here" />
                <input type="text" name="post" value={this.state.post} onChange={this.handleChange} maxLength="200" placeholder="Post here" />
                <input type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} value="Add Post" /> 
                <Allposts post={this.state.post} title={this.state.title} keyid={this.state.keyid} /> 
            </div>
            )
        }    
    }
```

AllPosts.js

```
class Allposts extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super();
this.state = {
  newObject : {
    post : '',
    title : '',
    keyid : ''
  },
  allPosts : []
}

}

render() {
        return (
          this.state.allPosts.map((post) =><div>
          { post.post}{post.title}{post.keyid}
          </div>
)
          )
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve your problem would be to keep AllPosts and Addpost component isolated and rendered by their component Parents

post.js

```
class Post extends React.Component {
   state: {
      allPosts: []
   }
   addPost = (post) => {
      this.setState(prev => ({allPosts: prev.allPosts.concat([post])}))
   }
   render() {
      <>
         <Addpost addPost={this.addPost}/>
         <AllPosts allPosts={this.state.allPosts} />
      </>
   }
}
```

---

Addpost.js

```
class Addpost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  
          title : '',
          post : '',
          keyid : 0
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value
      })
    }

    handleClick() {
        const { keyid, post, title } = this.state;
        const post = { keyid, post, title };
        this.props.addPost(post)
        this.setState(prevState => ({   
            keyid : prevState.keyid + 1,
            post : '',
            title : ''
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} maxLength="30" placeholder="Title here" />
                <input type="text" name="post" value={this.state.post} onChange={this.handleChange} maxLength="200" placeholder="Post here" />
                <input type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} value="Add Post" />  
            </div>
        )
     }    
}
```

---

Allposts.js

```
const Allposts = () => {
   return (
        this.props.allPosts.map((post) => (
           <div>
            { post.post} {post.title} {post.keyid}
           </div>
        ))
   )   
}
```

However if you want to pass props only after clicking, you would need to maintain a state that says clicked or not. and then pass props like

```
const { clicked, post, keyid, title } = this.state;
const newProp = { post, keyid, title };

<AllPost {...(clicked? newProps: {})} />
```

Comment: Regarding your part of answer about passing props when button is clicked, it will happen once as clicked state will be set true on first click of button. But how am i going to set it to false again so that after every button click, data from input fields is sent to other components. hence between clicks, props is kept in its own component.

Comment: @Alternatingpulse I will personally suggest you with the first approach, as that is the right way to design your system, but you could always clear state in setState callback.